# HTML type="search" detect clear button support

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, webkit, cross-browser

In HTML5 we have the [`<input type="search" />`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.search.html) which acts differently on multiple browsers.

Webkit adds a clear button when text is added and Firefox does not.

Is there a way; other than browser sniffing, to detect if the clear button is supported by the browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best answer I can come up with at the moment. It is one level under browser sniffing. It can break easily with browser upgrades or users changing the default behavior with generic CSS rules.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="t1" class="tb"/><br/>
    <input type="search" id="s1" class="tb"/><br/>
    <input type="search" id="s2" class="tb"/><br/><br/>
    <textarea id="ta" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        var supported = {

            getCSSValue: function(element, property) {
                var cs = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null);
                return cs.getPropertyValue(property);
            },

            _makeSearchElem : function(){    
                var element = document.createElement("input");
                element.setAttribute("type","search");    
                return element;
            },

            //checks to see if type="search" is supported
            searchType : function(){
                var elm = this._makeSearchElem();
                var result = this._searchType( elm );
                elm = null;
                //redefine so we do not have to recalc this every call
                this.searchType = function(){
                    return result;
                }
                return result;
            },

            _searchType : function(element){        
                return element.type === "search";
            },

            //checks to see if type="search" is supported AND it has the clean button
            //This is almost to the level of browser sniffing since only WebKit supports it at the moment
            searchTypeWithClearButton : function( ){

                /*
                    Assumes that the developer does not disable the clear button with CSS
                        input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button { -webkit-appearance: none; }
                    Only way to detect that would be to walk the style sheet and regex match the selector and cssText [Yuck]
                */

                var isSearchWithClear = false;

                var element = this._makeSearchElem();
                element.style.display = "none";            

                //Before we check CSS make sure the type is search
                if(this._searchType( element )){

                    //Add element to page flow so we can read the computed style
                    document.body.appendChild( element );        
                    var webkitAppearance = this.getCSSValue(element, "-webkit-appearance");
                    document.body.removeChild( element );

                    isSearchWithClear = webkitAppearance === "searchfield";  //this may break if someone adds a generic class to change it to textfield.

                }

                element = null;

                //redefine so we do not have to recalc every call
                this.searchTypeWithClearButton = function(){
                    return isSearchWithClear;
                }

                return isSearchWithClear;

            }

        }        

        /*
        //    Running basic tests:
        */

        //Check for just search
        var x1 = supported.searchType();
        var str = "Supports search: \t" + x1 + "\n";

        //Check for just search again, make sure cached value works
        var x2 = supported.searchType();
        str += "Supports search [run 2]: \t" + x2 + "\n";


        //Check for search with clear button
        var x3 = supported.searchTypeWithClearButton();
        str += "Supports search with clear button: \t" + x3 + "\n";

        //Check for search with clear button again, make sure cached value works
        var x4 = supported.searchTypeWithClearButton();
        str += "Supports search with clear button  [run 2]: \t" + x4;

        document.getElementById("ta").value = str;

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

This about the only reliable way - try to create a search element and see if the change 'sticks':

```
var i = document.createElement('input');
var orig = document.getAttribute('type');
i.setAttribute('type', 'search');
if (orig != i.getAttribute('type')) {
   ... supported ...
}
```

You can use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to handle the detection duties for you, though.

Comment: This is NOT what I am asking. Firefox will say it is type=search, BUT it does not support the clear button. I want to check to see if the clear button is there.

Comment: Then I'd suggest viewing the input object's config using the various browsers' debugger tools to see if there's some mention of the clear button, or a clear event attached to it.

Comment: Been there already, asked this question, hoping someone had insight.