# Detect input type search clear button in Chrome (and IE10)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10

I've written a plugin, which imitates the behavior of a Chrome search input field. (Having an X, which clears the input).

However, Chrome and IE10 are supporting such behavior natively, so I don't want to apply the plugin in those browsers.

I found a way for IE10. Inject a style element into the DOM, that hides the pseudo elements "::-ms-clear" (that's the x the IE inserts into text inputs) and then check if the pseudo element in the certain input has 'display: none'.

Chrome also adds a pseudo element: "-webkit-search-cancel-button" and I'm also capable of hiding it with CSS, however I'm not able to determine whether it's hidden or not, using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle), because Chrome always returns the result of the input itself, instead of the pseudo element.
Thanks in advance :)

```
(function () {

    function hasNativeClearButton(input) {
        var inputCopy = input.cloneNode(),
            head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            style = document.createElement('style'),
            css = '.cc-clearinput-already-supported-test { position: absolute;display: block; } .cc-clearinput-already-supported-test::-ms-clear { display: none; } .cc-clearinput-already-supported-test::clear { display: none; } .cc-clearinput-already-supported-test::-webkit-search-cancel-button { display: none; }';


        style.textContent = css;
        head.insertBefore(style, null);

        inputCopy.className = 'cc-clearinput-already-supported-test';
        inputCopy.value = 'aValue';
        document.body.insertBefore(inputCopy, null);


        alert(window.getComputedStyle(inputCopy, '::-ms-clear').display);
        alert(window.getComputedStyle(inputCopy, '::-webkit-search-cancel-button').display);

        head.removeChild(style);
        document.body.removeChild(inputCopy);

    }

    var daInput = document.createElement('input');
    daInput.type = 'search';
    hasNativeClearButton(daInput);

})()
```

Comment: Why not use type=text and avoid the workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML type="search" detect clear button support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942207/html-type-search-detect-clear-button-support)